# Percent sign in bash is not typeable

Tags: linux, bash, settings, ubuntu-12.04

I have a strange problem: I cannot type or copy the percent sign in my bash...

I tried to read `~/.bashrc`, `/etc/profile` (and stuff in `/etc/profile.d`). I also tried "`sudo bash`", but still not possible to type "`%`". Percent sign in "`sh`" works...

Any suggestions?

```
uname -a
Linux 3.2.0-65-generic #99-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jul 4 21:03:29 UTC 2014 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

BTW: Question moved to: https://superuser.com/questions/890645/percent-sign-in-bash-is-not-typeable

Comment: This sounds like it could possibly be a keyboard mapping issue. Are there any other keys that don't give you the expected character? Either way, this question isn't really on topic here, as it is not specifically related to programming. You might have more luck asking on http://superuser.com

Comment: As long as I know the other keys are working correctly...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround is using the ascii value 37: Press and hold the ALT-key, enter 37 on your numeric keyboard and release the ALT-key.

A solution is checking the keyboard mapping. Hold the shift and try all the numbers. On my keyboard I have

```
!@#$%^&*()
```

Do you have an old keyboard somewhere that you could try?

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions: `ALT+37` does not work in Terminal, could not check in virtual console (other problem...). The keyboard mapping is ok: `xmodmap -pke | grep percent` gives `keycode  14 = 5 percent 5 percent`. I can also change it, e.g.: `xmodmap -e "keycode 14 = 5 U203D 5 UD203D"` which prints the character ‽ when pressing `SHIFT+5`.

Comment: BTW: its the same with a different keyboard... Another hint could be that I even can not copy the %-sign from clipboard into the Terminal...

Comment: Without clibboard  `printf "\x$(printf %x 37)"` will fail too. How about `printf "\x25"` ?

Comment: The first expression fails, because of the % sign inside... The second expression works! The first time I see a % in the gnome-terminal. Great!

Comment: I used the second expression to generate the %-sign for the first expression, and the result is also a %-sign. `printf "\x$(printf $(printf "\x25")x 37)\n"`

Comment: Now you assign the % to a variable or function key !

Comment: Well, I would like to solve the problem at its root, not just have a workaround... Any further idea where so search?

Comment: What is your `locale`? Do you have `LANG=en_US.UTF-8` Do you have a ~/.Xmodmap file? Is /etc/sysconfig/console default (with `CONSOLE_SCREENMAP="trivial"` and without  KEYMAP_CORRECTIONS ) ? Try to find something with http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/954/how-does-keyboard-mapping-work-in-linux .

Comment: There were two lines in `.inputrc` which were commented wrong. See http://superuser.com/questions/890645/percent-sign-in-bash-is-not-typeable Thanks for all the help!

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem with the mapping of the backspace button. Instead of deleting previous characters while editing files it would appear "^?" . I used "stty sane" in the command line and it was reset. Maybe that helps.